# snakemake threads wildcards not found

Tags: python, bioinformatics, snakemake

I have a snakemake rule like:

```
rule get_coverage:
    input: 
        cram=lambda wildcards: expand(config['input']['cram'][wildcards.reference_genome], #access_id = access_id[wildcards.sample_name], 
                                        sample_name='{sample_name}'), 
        bai=lambda wildcards: expand(config['input']['cram'][wildcards.reference_genome] + '.crai', #access_id = access_id[wildcards.sample_name], 
                                        sample_name='{sample_name}'),
        ref=lambda wildcards: config['reference_genome'][wildcards.reference_genome],
        chrom_size=lambda wildcards: config['chrom_size'][wildcards.reference_genome]
    output: 
        coverage=directory(config['output']['median_coverage'])
    conda: 
        src + '/env/acc_mask.yml'
    threads: 19
    script: 
        """
        mosdepth \
            -n \
            -t {threads} \
            --use-median \
            -f {input.ref} \
            -b {input.chrom_size} \
            {output.median_coverage} \
            {input.cram}
        """
```

I got a error:

```
RuleException:
NameError in line xxx of xxx.smk:
The name 'threads' is unknown in this context. Please make sure that you defined that variable. Also note that braces not used for variable access have to be ...
```

In my impression, threads, as a wildcards, can be replaced in the shell. Is there anything wrong with my script?

Comment: I'd say the main issue here is that `script` expects a script file. Instead you pass to `script` a string that presumably you want to execute with the `shell` directive.

Comment: As @dariober said, this is essentially a typo - voting to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that `{threads}` can be used in a `shell` directive. It cannot be used in a `script` directive however. Your `rule` contains the latter, so fixing that should make it work:

```py
rule get_coverage:
    input: 
        cram=lambda wildcards: expand(config['input']['cram'][wildcards.reference_genome], #access_id = access_id[wildcards.sample_name], 
                                        sample_name='{sample_name}'), 
        bai=lambda wildcards: expand(config['input']['cram'][wildcards.reference_genome] + '.crai', #access_id = access_id[wildcards.sample_name], 
                                        sample_name='{sample_name}'),
        ref=lambda wildcards: config['reference_genome'][wildcards.reference_genome],
        chrom_size=lambda wildcards: config['chrom_size'][wildcards.reference_genome]
    output: 
        coverage=directory(config['output']['median_coverage'])
    conda: 
        src + '/env/acc_mask.yml'
    threads: 19
    shell: 
        """
        mosdepth \
            -n \
            -t {threads} \
            --use-median \
            -f {input.ref} \
            -b {input.chrom_size} \
            {output.median_coverage} \
            {input.cram}
        """
```

Comment: *[Threads] cannot be used in a script directive*. I'm not sure this is correct... E.g., in an R script you can access threads from `snakemake@threads`. The main issue here is that `script` expects a script file not a string of bash commands.

Comment: `snakemake.threads` is also available within Python scripts through the `snakemake` object. However as far as I know, I interpret the error message and understand the documentation, only for `shell` the `{threads}` placeholder is available.